# Expedia QuickConnect: The namespace specified is invalid

Tags: php, xml

when I make a AvailRateUpdate I receive this error: "The namespace specified is invalid"
Here you can find my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<AvailRateUpdateRQ xmlns="http://www.expediaconnect.com/EQC/AR/2011/06">

<Authentication username="myeqcuser" password="myeqcpass"/>

<Hotel id="myhotelid"/>

<AvailRateUpdate>

<DateRange from="2011-11-11" to="2011-11-30"/>

<RoomType id="200050122">

<RatePlan id="200295014" closed="false">

<Rate currency="EUR">

<PerOccupancy rate="60.00" occupancy="1"/>

<PerOccupancy rate="100.00" occupancy="2"/>

<PerOccupancy rate="135.00" occupancy="3"/>

<PerOccupancy rate="160.00" occupancy="4"/>

</Rate>

</RatePlan>

</RoomType>

</AvailRateUpdate>

</AvailRateUpdateRQ>
```

here instead, you can find my AR URL:
https://ws.expediaquickconnect.com/connect/ar

where I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

AvailRateUpdateRQ - for request and AvailRateUpdateRS for response